# Какой php framework сейчас  актуален?

Tags: framework, php

меня интересует разработка сайтов, внутренних корпоративных порталов и тд.

Comment: Холиварный вопрос. Уже как-то отвечал.

[С какого фреймворка стоит начать?][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/182748/php-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой - CodeIgniter. Мощный - Symfony 2. Нечто среднее - Yii. ИМХО конечно же

Answer (score 0):

смотря для каких целей))) я юзаю codeIgniter - оч прост и понятен в использовании